# How to serve 2 different versions of websites under the same domain?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, nginx, architecture

I have started working on a project that needs a re-write. So, instead of doing a big bang release
we have decided to use [Strangler Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerFigApplication.html) which means the following

- The current application (stack details below) will be running as is under the existing domain https://app.com
- The existing (and new) features will be re-written in a new stack (details below) and deployed in parallel to the existing app (under the same domain https://app.com)

The requirements are

- The end-user always works with the same domain https://app.com
- Any existing feature migrated to a new app or a new feature is available by the under the same domain https://app.com

The stack and architecture of the current app is

- HTML files with hardcoded data
- CSS files
- font files
- PDFs
- images
- flash files
  among other things.

Thee application is static. It has no database. It makes calls to other 3rd party APIs but does not have its own database (other than the files, and the images)

It sits under a directory and is served by running a web server (Apache) on a private dedicated server.

The stack and architecture of new re-write will

- Use React or Gatsby
- A standard build system that generates the static files
- The data (PDF, Images) hosted somewhere else
- Flash files (until we figure out a better way)

Given these requirements, I thought of having 2 versions of the app using some sort of load balancer such as `Nginx` and serve the URL patterns using a proxy.

For example

- a request coming to https://app.com/productPage.html goes to existing app deployment (assuming it is **not** migrated)
- a request coming to https://app.com/profilePage goes to existing app deployment (assuming it is migrated)

Now, considering this situation, I want to ask the following question

- Is this approach looks sane? Are there better ways to deal with this situation?
- How to implement such a reverse-proxy based system (considering Nginx)? (or if there is a better way)

I would love to hear out ideas and any resources/books/github that can help me learn and implement this.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is there any backend in your app, or it's completely static?

Comment: @georg, it is completely static. It uses some external 3rd party APIs but no database exists for this app. Thanks for the great question! I will update the details above

Comment: When do you expect to know if the image you are seeing is the new or the old app? When is nginx supposed to proxy to one or the other?

Comment: Great question, I guess I missed this part. The images are static so the new app will copy them to its own project folder, or serve it from S3 (or its variants). I *think* as long as it is the same image (as it would have been served by an old app), everything seems good! Am I missing anything?

Comment: Let's say you have an old functionality at abc.html. And then you migrated this to a new one. We would recommend you create code with the same extension but put it under a different url. Like http://app.com/abc.html and after migration it would be http://app.com/v2/abc.html. And all the links in your code should now point to v2.

Comment: Good idea @SagarAgrawal. How would this approach work if someone has bookmarked the page (with no version), wouldn't experience be broken at this time?

Comment: In such cases the first line of code to redirect has to be implemented in http://app.com/abc.html which will redirect the user to v2. We usually do that in angular or react using the router. But in your case since its purely static and no frameworks, you can simply redirect the user to v2 using JS.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a v2 of pages that has been migrated to new functionality. And all links to the page should be updated to point to v2.

If anyone has done bookmark to old links, then those pages can simply redirect the user to the v2 ones by simply redirecting them using JS - window.location(url_of_target_page);

Comment: Doesn't that answer assume that the new version of the code lives in the same old codebase? We still need a load balancer to proxy request, right? since there are 2 apps running under the same domain

Comment: In fact this approach is better because you don’t have to maintain two code base. One code base will help in build process and deployment part. And since app is same your current load balancer should work fine.

Comment: But we do not want to continue developing in the current codebase. Please read the question for more details